# Colon difference in Matlab and Python

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, syntax

What is the equivalent to `someArray(:,1,1)` in python from Matlab?

In python `someArray[:][0][0]` produces a different value

Comment: How is the output different? What is the expected and actual output? Are you using NumPy arrays?

Comment: In Python, `someArray[:]` makes a copy of someArray so `someArray[:][0][0]` would first make a copy of someArray, then return the zeroth item of the zeroth item of someArray. In other words, it is equivalent to `someArray[0][0]`.

Comment: @Justin - OH!  Suddenly you cleared up all my confusion on `:` in regular Python.  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`someArray[:,0,0]` is the <strike>Python</strike> NumPy equivalent of MATLAB's `someArray(:,1,1)`.  I've never figured out how to do it in pure Python, the colon slice operation is a total mystery to me with lists-of-lists.